# Mapear 2 jsons e renderizar em 1 componente card + formatação de data

Tags: json, react

Gostaria de uma ajuda: Tenho dois Json: posts e author. O Json posts retorna certinho no log. Cada post tem um respectivo autor. Já está mostrando o os cards com o post certinho, mas preciso mostrar também o autor desse post pegando o nome do segundo JSon e mostrar no mesmo card. E tbm preciso formatar a data do post que está vindo como: "publishedAt": 1492004832000. Preciso formatar e separar dia, mês e ano.

Grato pela atenção

JSONs : Publicações: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3fa2f000082000fc3f8 
Autores: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3ae2f00005b000fc3f6

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from './services/api';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import PostCard from './components/PostCard';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPosts() {
      const response = await api.get('5be5e3fa2f000082000fc3f8');

      const postsApi = response.data;

      setPosts(postsApi);
    }
    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="cards">
          {posts?.map((post, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <PostCard post={post} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma resolução possível seria:

**App.js**

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import "./styles.css";
 import axios from "axios";
 import PostCard from "./PostCard";

 export default function App() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [authors, setAuthors] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
       async function loadPosts() {
         axios
           .get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3fa2f000082000fc3f8")
           .then(res => {
             setPosts(res.data);
           });
       }
        loadPosts();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
     async function loadAuthors() {
       axios
       .get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3ae2f00005b000fc3f6")
       .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          setAuthors(res.data);
      });
    }

     loadAuthors();
  }, []);

  const getAuthor = id => {
     let ret = authors.filter((author, i) => {
       return author.id === id;
    });

      console.log(ret[0].name);
        return ret[0].name;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
  {posts
    ? posts.map(element => (
        <PostCard
          key={element.metadata.publishedAt}
          post={element}
          author={getAuthor(element.metadata.authorId)}
        />
      ))
    : ""}
  </div>
 );
}
```

**PostCard.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default function PostCard({ post, author }) {
  const convertDate = date => {
    let newDate = new Date(date);
   return newDate.toLocaleDateString();
  };

 return (
   <div key={post.metadata.publishedAt}>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>{convertDate(post.metadata.publishedAt)}</p>
      <p>Author: {author}</p>
      <p>{post.body}</p>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show!!! Obrigado!